# Two subgroups are isomorphic and one is contained inside the other

Tags: group-theory

We know that there is a bijection between the sets $\mathbb{Z}$ and $2\mathbb{Z}$. But $\mathbb{Z}\neq2\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $H$ and $H'$ be two isomorphic subgroups of a group $G$. If $H'\subseteq H$ then can we say that $H'=H$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I asked the question and I realized how stupid this question is (since the question itself has the answer ).

Answer (score 2):

If $H$ and $H'$ are finite, then yes. The inclusion $H'\subset H$ is sufficient, since they are the same order. On the other hand, if they aren't finite, then your counter example works since $2\Bbb{Z}\subset \Bbb{Z},$ they are also isomorphic, but they are not equal.